# Making box width full inside card bootstrap 4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have following Bootstrap  code. I am trying to do inside card is in full width. As of now it shows extra space in left and right. I need to avoid that space and should fit in the main card.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="card">
  <h5 class="card-header">testing</h5>
  <div class="card-body">
    <div ng-bind-html="desc"></div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-block">
          <div class="row no-gutters">
            <div class="col">
              <img class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x300" alt="image">
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <img class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x300" alt="image">
            </div>
           </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my try, I have added `px-0` next to `card-body` class,
and `w-100` in the `<img>` elements is optional, you can delete it if that is unnecessary.
Hope this works!

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="card">
            <h5 class="card-header">testing</h5>
            <div class="card-body p-0">
                <div ng-bind-html="desc"></div>
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-block">
                        <div class="row no-gutters">
                            <div class="col">
                                <img class="img-fluid w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x300.png" alt="image">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col">
                                <img class="img-fluid w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x300.png" alt="image">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: The box shows space in left and right inside main card

Comment: @atc Oops, understand now, thank for the highlight! Now updated

Comment: for me all items stretch to fit inside card.

Comment: @atc if that so, just add `p-0` next to `card-body` class

Comment: no its not working

Comment: is there any posibility that you have external css that override the p-0 style?

Comment: no its not overriding

Comment: The solution is apply p-0 and then manually give padding wherever required